# Libsvm always gives same probability output

Tags: matlab, svm, probability, libsvm

I am new on Libsvm. I am using it in a project where I have data of positive and negative classes in the training set. I label positives as 1 and -1 to negatives. I train my classifier like that:

```
MODEL = l_svmtrain([labelPos;labelNeg],svmTBL,'-b 1');
```

where svmTBL is the data which positives and negatives are concatinated.

I test my data as follow:

```
[lab,acc,prob] = l_svmpredict(1,windowMaxPoolVector, MODEL, '-q -b 1');
```

Whichever test data I use, I always get [0.667,0,333] probability output and it does not make sense. I give 0 matrix ones matrix, ,t does not matter, output is always same. What might be the problem?

Thanks